Type of diodes for 9V
I am looking to protect a 9v battery against a 12v battery.
I know the question has been asked already and someone did put a circuit up as well but I don’t know what type or what model number I need to get.
I’m sorry to create this post but unfortunately I don’t have the privilege to comment on the other post.
Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thank you
SB

Post a picture of the circuit

General purpose or Schottky (bit more expensive, but generally less voltage drop = more efficient) with a reverse voltage rating of at least 15V, 25 or 50V preferred and a forward current rating of at least the maximum current you expect to see, preferably 2x or more.
